Flutter Share directly with Twitter(X) dm
What I want is that the user can press a button to share to Twitter DM, and not to post it. Is this possible? How can it be done?
All the libraries that I've tried all make posts, but I want to be able to do it with a DM.
I have also tried to search on Twitter(X)'s website itself, but i couldn't find anything there.

First Create account on X developer portal. Then in this account to get APIKEY, SECRATEKEY, TOKEN.
and then after this code use.
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:oauth1/oauth1.dart' as oauth1;

class TwitterService {
 final String apiKey = 'YOUR_API_KEY';
 final String apiSecretKey = 'YOUR_API_SECRET_KEY';
 final String accessToken = 'USER_ACCESS_TOKEN';
 final String accessTokenSecret = 'USER_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET';

 Future<void> sendDM(String recipientId, String message) async {
  final platform = oauth1.Platform(
  'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token',
  'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize',
  'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token',
  oauth1.SignatureMethods.hmacSha1,
);

final clientCredentials = oauth1.ClientCredentials(apiKey, apiSecretKey);
final credentials = oauth1.Credentials(accessToken, accessTokenSecret);

final client = oauth1.Client(
  platform.signatureMethod,
  clientCredentials,
  credentials,
);

final response = await client.post(
  Uri.parse('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/direct_messages/events/new.json'),
  body: jsonEncode({
    'event': {
      'type': 'message_create',
      'message_create': {
        'target': {'recipient_id': recipientId},
        'message_data': {'text': message}
      }
    }
  }),
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
);

if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  print('DM sent successfully');
} else {
  print('Failed to send DM: ${response.statusCode}');
    }
  }
}

and Elevated button on Press this function use like this.
final twitterService = TwitterService();
final recipientId = '123456789';
final message = 'Hello from Flutter!';

twitterService.sendDM(recipientId, message);

